# Gaming AI, courage and retaliation

Tags: graphing-functions, 3d

This is a bit oblique but maybe some of you will find it fun and it's been wrecking my brain for a while. Here's the background of what I'm trying to achieve, but if you want to skip to the actual maths part of the problem skip to ***THE MATHS***

So I have a computer controlled character in my game, and I want to calculate the probability R that he will retaliate when attacked (ranging from 0 to 100). This probability should be based on two variables, first the AI's remaining health H (the nearer to death, the more likely to run, again ranging from 0 to 100) and also the AI's courage C (which ranges from 0 to 100). At 0 courage, the AI will flee regardless of health. At 100 courage, the AI will retaliate regardless of health. At 50 courage, the chance of retaliation R will equal remaining health (R = H).

I know there are workarounds like writing endless if statements, but I'm after a clean formula that will give me R for all combinations of C and H. So far, I've approached the problem by drawing a line graph plotting R against H for some given value of C, and then modifying the result using C in some way. For example:

***THE MATHS***

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y05Om.png

Here is a graph plotting two variables R and H. The relationship between the two variables will be modified by a third variable C, which ranges from 0 to 100. When C = 50, then R = H (the black line). When C = 100, R = 100 (the green line). When C = 75, the blue line will be true, such that a 45degree diagonal line drawn between the black line and the green line will always intersect the blue line at its halfway point (as shown by the red line).

Is there a formula that can calculate R for any given values of H and C?
It would be an extra helpful bonus if the same pattern can be mirrored the other side of the line R =H for values of C less than 50.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have specified nine important points:
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c}
\text{Courage} (C) & \text{Health} (H) & \text{Probability} (P) \\
\hline
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 50 & 0 \\
0 & 100 & 0 \\
50 & 0 & 0 \\
50 & 50 & 50 \\
50 & 100 & 100 \\
100 & 0 & 100 \\
100 & 50 & 100 \\
100 & 100 & 100 \\
\end{array}$$
Looking at the data, it looks like a second-degree polynomial should work. So, let's fit the data to
$$\begin{aligned}
P(C, H) &= \sum_{i=0}^2 \sum_{j=0}^2 x_{i,j} C^i H^j \\
\;      &= x_{22} C^2 H^2 + x_{21} C^2 H + x_{20} C^2 + x_{12} C H^2 + x_{11} C H + x_{10} C + x_{02} H^2 + x_{01} H + x_{00}\\
\end{aligned}$$
Supplying the above polynomial and the nine known points to Sagemath *solve()*, we find a solution:
$$P(C, H) = -\frac{C^2 H}{2500} + \frac{C^2}{50} + \frac{C H}{25} - C = \frac{C \left ( 100 H - 2500 + C ( 50 - H ) \right )}{2500}$$

[image: Fit surface plot]

Do note that this function reaches $P(75, 100) = 112.5$ and $P(25, 0) = -12.5$, so you might wish to clamp the result to the the range 0 to 100.

You could implement this (in pseudocode) as

```
Function ProbabilityOfRetaliation(Courage, Health):
    Let  P = C * (100*H - 2500 + C*(50 - H)) / 2500
    If P < 0:
        Return 0
    Else If P <= 100:
        Return P
    Else:
        Return 100
    End If
End Function
```

Also note that the probability function is always linear in health (except for clipping, where the probability is clamped to range $[0, 100]$).

Comment: Thanks! This looks better than any of the sloppy solutions I've been coming up with, and should be fairly straightforward to implement in the code. Also, that wave graphic is awesome.

Comment: @CameronSnell: You're welcome! I used Gnuplot for the graph (drawing it as SVG, and Inkscape to clean it up a bit and convert the text to paths) and Sagemath to solve the coefficients (nine points/equations for nine unknowns); all free and open source programs.  I wrote my answer this way, because I'm hoping that others with a similar problem finding your question can see how to develop their own answer based on this. :)